# FFmpeg python doesn't merge

Tags: python, ffmpeg, youtube-dl, ffmpeg-python

I was making this youtube downloader GUI with Python: it asks for the URL, gives you a list with the possible quality settings and downloads the selected video file and the best audio file with youtube-dl. However, when I tell ffmpeg to merge the two separate downloaded files, it doesn't do anything and it doesn't say anything in the console either. Is there anything I'm missing?

Here's the relevant part of the code (starts at line 153):

```
            #Adding input arguments for ffmpeg
            ffmpeg_video = ffmpeg.input(self.video_title)
            ffmpeg_audio = ffmpeg.input(self.audio_title)
            output_ffmpeg_title = './videos/' + self.youtube_title
            #Merging with ffmpeg
            out = ffmpeg.output(ffmpeg_video, ffmpeg_audio, output_ffmpeg_title, vcodec='copy', acodec='aac')
            out.run
```

Here's the full code:

```
import youtube_dl
import tkinter as tk
import operator
import ffmpeg
class GUI:
    def __init__(self):
        #Creating initial window
        self.window = tk.Tk()
        self.window.title('YTDL')
        self.window.geometry('300x70')
        
        self.urlbox = tk.Entry(self.window)
        self.urlbox.pack(padx=5,pady=5)
        #Creating download button, which will open the format selection window
        downbutton = tk.Button(self.window, text="Download", command= self.check_url)
        downbutton.pack(padx=5, pady=5)
        #Creating a variable to keep track of the point in the GUI options selection
        self.format_select_process = False
        
        self.window.mainloop()
    def check_url(self):
        #Saving selected URL to variable
        self.selected_url = self.urlbox.get()
        self.urlbox.delete(0, 'end')
        #If something was written in the URL box, try to go the next step
        if len(self.selected_url) != 0:
            self.get_formats(self.selected_url)
        else:
            print('URL box is empty!')
    def get_formats(self, x):
        with youtube_dl.YoutubeDL() as ydl:
            meta = ydl.extract_info(x, download=False)
            #Save formats from 'meta' to 'self.formats'
            self.formats = meta.get('formats', [meta])
            self.youtube_title = meta.get('title', [meta])
            #Creating two dictionaries for the list of format sizes and extensions
            self.f_list_size_dict = {}
            self.f_list_ext_dict = {}
            #Creating audio format list
            self.audio_format_list = []
        #For every format in self.formats, add its format, extension, fps and filesize to self.f_list
        for f in self.formats:
            self.f_list = '-' + f['format']+ ' -' + f['ext'] + ' -' + str(f['fps']) + ' ' + str(f['filesize'])
            if 'audio only' in f['format']:
                #Add an element to each dictonary whose name is the format ID and whose value is its filesize/extension
                self.f_list_size_dict[f['format'].split(' -')[0]] = f['filesize']
                self.f_list_ext_dict[f['format'].split(' -')[0]] = f['ext']
                #Add to the audio format list the current audio format ID
                self.audio_format_list.append(f['format'].split(' -')[0])
        print('Audio format list:')
        print(self.audio_format_list)
        print('Size list dict:')
        print(self.f_list_size_dict)
        print('Ext list size dict:')
        print(self.f_list_ext_dict)
        """
        #Making a new list which only contains the audio format IDs
        self.audio_format_list = str(self.f_list_size_dict.keys()).split('([')[1]
        self.audio_format_list = self.audio_format_list.split('])')[0]
        self.audio_format_list = self.audio_format_list.replace("'", "")
        self.audio_format_list = self.audio_format_list.split(', ')
        print('Cleaned up audio format list:')
        print(self.audio_format_list)
        """
        #Here the program starts looking for the best audio format
        #In the try block, the program gets the best audio format's ID from the size dict and extension from the ext dict
        #In the except block, the program gets the ID from the audio format list and the extension from the ext dict
        try:
            self.highest_audio = max(self.f_list_size_dict.items(), key=operator.itemgetter(1))[0]
            self.highest_audio_ext = self.f_list_ext_dict.get(self.highest_audio)
            print('Best audio format ID: ' + self.highest_audio)
            print('Best audio format extension: ' + self.highest_audio_ext)
        except:
            self.highest_audio = max(self.audio_format_list)
            self.highest_audio_ext = self.f_list_ext_dict.get(self.highest_audio)
            print(self.highest_audio)
            print(self.highest_audio_ext)
        #Going to next sted of the code, which renders the format choice window
        self.format_select()
    def format_select(self):
        self.window.withdraw()
        format_select_window = tk.Toplevel()
        format_select_window.attributes('-topmost', True)
        format_select_window.geometry("300x350")
        format_select_window_label = tk.Label(format_select_window, text="Select the video format")
        format_select_window_label.pack(padx=5, pady=5)
        format_select_window.protocol('WM_DELETE_WINDOW', lambda: exit())

        self.format_listbox = tk.Listbox(format_select_window, height=15, width=40, yscrollcommand=1)
        self.format_listbox.pack(padx=10, pady=10)
        for index, item in enumerate(self.f_list):
            self.f_list_lenght = index
        download_button = tk.Button(format_select_window, text='Download', command=self.download)
        download_button.pack(padx=10, pady=10)
        #Adding options to the listbox
        for f in self.formats:
            #If it is adding an audio only format, it will add the ID, filesize (if possible with try block) and extension
            if 'audio only' in f['format'] + ' ' + str(f['fps']) + ' FPS ' + f['ext']:
                try:
                    mb_filesize = round(f['filesize'] / 1024 / 1024, 2)
                    self.format_listbox.insert(self.f_list_lenght, f['format'] + ' ' + str(mb_filesize) + ' MiB  ' + f['ext']) 
                except:
                    self.format_listbox.insert(self.f_list_lenght, f['format'] + '  ' + f['ext'])
            #If it is adding a video format, it will add the ID, FPS, filesize (if possible with the try block) and extension
            else:
                try:
                    mb_filesize = round(f['filesize'] / 1024 / 1024, 2)
                    self.format_listbox.insert(self.f_list_lenght, f['format'] + ' ' + str(f['fps']) + ' FPS' + ' ' + str(mb_filesize) + ' MiB  ' + f['ext'])
                except:
                    self.format_listbox.insert(self.f_list_lenght, f['format'] + ' ' + str(f['fps']) + ' FPS  ' + f['ext'])
    def download(self):
        #Getting the list position of the selected format
        selected_format_list_position = self.format_listbox.curselection()
        #Getting the text of the selected format list item
        selected_format = self.format_listbox.get(selected_format_list_position)
        print('Selected format: ' + selected_format)
        #Cutting from the selected format list item text everything past ' -' to only get the format's ID
        selected_format_id = selected_format.split(' -')[0]
        print('Selected format ID: ' + selected_format_id)
        #Converting the ID to string
        final_selected_format_id = str(selected_format_id)
        print('Final selected format: ' + final_selected_format_id)
        #Cutting from the selected format list item text everything before '  ' to only get the extension
        final_ext = selected_format.split('  ')[1]
        print('Final video extension: ' + final_ext)
        if 'audio only' in selected_format:
            #Creating the download options dictionary (not working):
            #Setting the download location to the videos folder,
            #preventing the program from downloading a whole playlist,
            #telling youtube-dl to extract audio ('x'),
            #giving youtube-dl the requested format (which is only audio).
            self.ydl_opts = {'outtmpl':'./videos/%(title)s.%(ext)s', 'noplaylist': True, 'x': True, 'format': final_selected_format_id}
            #Downloading
            with youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(self.ydl_opts) as ydl:
                ydl.download([self.selected_url])
        elif 'audio only' not in selected_format:
            #Adding '+bestaudio' to the selected format ID (which is only a video ID in this case)
            final_selected_format_id_video_audio = str(selected_format_id) + '+bestaudio'
            #Creating the download options dictionary:
            #Setting the download location to the videos folder,
            #preventing the program from downloading a whole playlist,
            #giving youtube-dl the requested format with audio.
            self.ydl_opts = {'outtmpl':'./videos/%(title)s.%(ext)s', 'noplaylist': True, 'format': final_selected_format_id_video_audio}
            #Predicting the video file title and location for future ffmpeg merge
            self.video_title = './videos/' + self.youtube_title + '.f' + str(selected_format_id) + '.' + final_ext
            print('Video file title: ' + self.video_title)
            #Predicting the audio file title and location for future ffmpeg merge
            self.audio_title = './videos/' + self.youtube_title + '.f' + str(self.highest_audio) + '.' + self.highest_audio_ext
            print('Audio file title: ' + self.audio_title)
            #Downloading with youtube-dl
            with youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(self.ydl_opts) as ydl:
                ydl.download([self.selected_url])
            #Adding input arguments for ffmpeg
            ffmpeg_video = ffmpeg.input(self.video_title)
            ffmpeg_audio = ffmpeg.input(self.audio_title)
            output_ffmpeg_title = './videos/' + self.youtube_title
            #Merging with ffmpeg
            ffmpeg.output(ffmpeg_video, ffmpeg_audio, output_ffmpeg_title, vcodec='copy', acodec='aac')
GUI()
```

If there is a better way of integrating ffmpeg with youtube-dl in Python, please tell me.

Answer (score 0):

- in your full code there is `run()` function is missing  .
- Try this

`ffmpeg.output(ffmpeg_video, ffmpeg_audio, output_ffmpeg_title, vcodec='copy', acodec='aac').run()`